# Word Count hadoop program: Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main

Tags: java, hadoop

I get this error while trying to compile Word Count hadoop program in Windows.

```
C:\Users\14108\eclipse-workspace>hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WC.java
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

I just copied the word count Hadoop program from hadoop.apache.org(v1) and saved it in a .java file.

I have added the tools.jar in the hadoop classpath as below as was recommended by many other solutions for the same question:

`C:\Users\14108\eclipse-workspace>hadoop classpath C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\etc\hadoop;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\common;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\common\*;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\lib\*;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\hdfs;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\hdfs\*;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\yarn;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\yarn\*;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*`

I still get the error while compiling. What am I missing?

No other solution on the internet for the same questions did not help me

Note: All this is in windows

Comment: I just copied it from the apache documentation.

Comment: I think you are using old Hadoop documentation. Besides, you would typically use `hadoop jar` with a JAR file, not run a Java file

Comment: Yes but to create an executable JAR file we would have to compile it right ? I am using hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WC.java command to first compile and then will create a JAR file

Answer (score 0):

This is solved now. Worked after reinstalling hadoop and setting all the environment variables again. *Wierd*